# YoutubeLiveStream API Error - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

When I am trying to use Youtube Live Stream API, I got errors like this.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

```
======================================================================
07:23:49.643 Traceback (most recent call last):
07:23:49.643   File "/usr/lib/enigma2/python/Components/PluginComponent.py", line 53, in readPluginList
07:23:49.643   File "/usr/lib/enigma2/python/Tools/Import.py", line 2, in my_import
07:23:49.643   File "/usr/lib/enigma2/python/Plugins/Extensions/YouTubeLiveStreaming/plugin.py", line 30, in <module>
07:23:49.644     import apiclient.discovery
07:23:49.644   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apiclient/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
07:23:49.644   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/sample_tools.py", line 32, in <module>
07:23:49.644   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/tools.py", line 70, in <module>
07:23:49.644     argparser = _CreateArgumentParser()
07:23:49.644   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/tools.py", line 55, in _CreateArgumentParser
07:23:49.644     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
07:23:49.644   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1586, in __init__
07:23:49.644 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
======================================================================
```

Comment: Thanks for including the traceback! I submitted a proposed edit to format the code block more nicely. If you just add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, it displays in a more readable way. Hopefully that helps you find an answer to your question!